# H2O R How to handle levels not trained on when predicting?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, h2o

I have a set of CSVs with a result column to train, and a set of test CSVs without the result column.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

train <- read.csv(train_file, header=T)
train.h2o <- as.h2o(train)
y <- "Result"
x <- setdiff(names(train.h2o), y)

model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = x,
                          y = y,
                          training_frame = train.h2o,
                          model_id = "my_model",
                          epochs = 5000,
                          hidden = c(50),
                          stopping_rounds=5,
                          stopping_metric="misclassification", 
                          stopping_tolerance=0.001,
                          seed = 1)



test <- read.csv(test_file, header=T)
test.h2o <- as.h2o(test)

pred <- h2o.predict(model,test.h2o)
```

When I try to predict the outcome with test data, I get a bunch of errors like:

```
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
Test/Validation dataset column 'ColumnName' has levels not trained on: [ABCD, BCDE]
```

H2O used to be able to handle data present in test but not during training. I found some posts online where they say they do. But it is not working for me.

How can I avoid these errors, and predict a value for the test data?

Comment: Can you turn this in to a reproducible example by using a publicly available dataset?  H2O should ignore new levels, so I don't know what's going on here (I haven't seen this error before) and if it's a bug, we want to be able to reproduce so we can fix it.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods you can have a try:

#### Use `factor` as oppose to `character`

Before feeding data into machine learning function, you can combine your train and test data, and convert `character` variable to `factor`.

Hence unique values will be recorded as level info even you split combined data later.

```
library(h2o)

h2o.init()

#using dummy data as combined training and testing data
prostatePath = system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package = "h2o")
prostate.hex = h2o.importFile(path = prostatePath, destination_frame = "prostate.hex")

#assuming GLEASON is the character variable, and transform it to factor
prostate.hex$GLEASON <- h2o.asfactor(prostate.hex$GLEASON)

#split data such that 0,4,5,8 only in test set, and not in train set.
h2o.test <- prostate.hex[prostate.hex$GLEASON %in% c("0","4","5","8"),]
h2o.train <- prostate.hex[!prostate.hex$GLEASON %in% c("0","4","5","8"),]

#train model
model <- h2o.glm(y = "CAPSULE", x = c("AGE","RACE","PSA","DCAPS","GLEASON"), training_frame = h2o.train,
       family = "binomial", nfolds = 0)

#predict without error
pred <- predict(model,h2o.test)
```

#### Use `one-hot-encoding` Explicitly

I know that `h2o` machine learning functions provide internal encoding methods (via `categorical_encoding` parameters) including one-hot-encoding, which turns character variable into lots of `1/0` integer variables.

As oppose to use this technique implicitly, you can use it explicitly.  Hence those levels don't exist in training will not be used in model.  New levels in testing are simply not used for prediction.

Comment: It is possible to use them, e.g., through clustering of features, but that is more of a statistics/machine learning question than a programming one.

Comment: That's good idea, which hides the individual level info behind new variable. We just need to be careful that some/a few clusters only exist in testing set.

Comment: Ideally you would have some sort of clustering algorithm on the training set and be able to apply the same criteria to the testing set to map variables/groups of variables to those clusters.

Comment: One common "feature of a feature" that you can cluster on is how frequently a specific class/level appears, as well as the average value of certain numeric variables that co-occur with it, or the incidence of other feature's missing variables with it. Possibly string length if the category is something like a URL, but then you might as well create a new variable just using the string length.

Comment: I tried using factor and same result. I explicitly put one hot encoding and same result. However, how can I combine the test data with the training data, if the test data does not have a result column? It is not really test data, it is actually the one that needs to be predicted.

Comment: @user7792598, the purpose of put train and test together is to convert character variables to factors, hence all levels in train and test are involved.  Results column can be assigned with dummy value (e.g. 0).  Test data will not be used in training, it just levels useful into in the training data that factors including all levels (which may be used in test).